# Perl Output from File error

Tags: perl, if-statement

Assuming the following input:

```
        for ($k = 0; $k < @tableb; $k++) {
        chomp ($tableb[$k]);
        ($netsta, $delay_time) = (split /\s+/,$tableb[$k])[1,9];
        ($net, $sta) = (split /\./, $netsta)[0,1];
        print $net, " ", $sta, "\n";
        if ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "DONT") {
                $stat = 1;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "MICH") {
                $stat = 2;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "LEON") {
                $stat = 3;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "RAPH") {
                $stat = 4;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "SPLN") {
                $stat = 5;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "SHRD") {
                $stat = 6;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "CASY") {
                $stat = 7;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "APRL") {
                $stat = 8;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "FOOT") {
                $stat = 9;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "BEBP") {
                $stat = 10;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "RKST") {
                $stat = 11;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "DUBY") {
                $stat = 12;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "SAMH") {
                $stat = 13;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "GRAW") {
                $stat = 14;
            } elsif ($net eq "ZJ" && $sta eq "KNYN") {
                $stat = 15;
            } else {

            }
        printf OUT "%s \n", $stat;

    }
```

I wish to take an output of net(network) and sta(station) from one file (As shown below), and then change the sta (station name indicated in the if/elsif conditionals), to a specific number (1-15).  My output, though not only prints numbers for the stations, but it prints out a 5 as well, most likely corresponding to the other lines outputted in 0 and 1.  I don't want the extra fives.  I just want the station numbers changed.

The Input file that I'm reading looks like:

```
MCCC processed: unknown event at: Thu, 16 Oct 2014 12:42:09 CST 
station, mccc delay,    std,    cc coeff,  cc std,   pol   , t0_times  ,        delay_times
 ZJ.CASY      0.4736    0.0000    0.9844    0.0288    0  CASY.BHZ   300.6973     0.0691
 ZJ.GRAW     -0.1526    0.0000    0.9853    0.0277    0  GRAW.BHZ   300.8462    -0.7059
 ZJ.RAPH      1.1169    0.0000    0.9845    0.0287    0  RAPH.BHZ   300.6406     0.7691
 ZJ.SHRD     -2.0157    0.0000    0.9439    0.0038    0  SHRD.BHZ   301.0593    -2.7821
 ZJ.SPLN      0.5778    0.0000    0.9858    0.0243    0  SPLN.BHZ   300.6516     0.2191
Mean_arrival_time:   300.2929 
No weighting of equations. 
Window:   2.94   Inset:   1.10  Shift:   0.25 
Variance: 0.00000   Coefficient: 0.97677  Sample rate:   40.000 
Taper:   0.37 
Phase: P        
PDE    2013 11 23  7 52 45.02   -17.117  -176.544  371.0  0.0  6.5
```

And currently, the if conditionals are supposed to be reading this information:

```
mccc 
ZJ CASY
ZJ GRAW
ZJ RAPH
ZJ SHRD
ZJ SPLN
300 2929
weighting 
2 94
0 00000
0 37
P 
2013
```

Finally, the end goal is, for each file in @tableb, I would like to print an output that looks like this:

```
$ filename
7
14
4
5
6
```

Comment: can you show sample input and output?

Comment: Please, please, please - turn on `strict` and `warnings` - it helps you find problems and mistakes in your code. It's optional in your own code, but when you're asking others for help, it's a basic initial troubleshooting step!

Comment: Also - sample inputs. We cannot troubleshoot your code that's outputting something unexpected if we don't know what's going _in_ to produce that output.

Comment: I apologize for not including an input.  I was writing this late last night and completely forgot.  The input looks like what I included above,

except repeated multiple times.  I had hoped with these if statements above, that if the first column equals "ZJ", AND if the second column ($sta) equals "DONT", "MICH", etc., that I would print out the new station number for each file (or event).  The event file that I'm pulling this information from is added above.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a hash, it would make the whole script more readable.
Without an input, I can only guess that you maybe have a second entry in your `@tableb`. For diagnostics, maybe `warn` the line so you can see where the `5`s comes from.

```
my $num = 1;
my %stationNumbers_ZJ = map {$_ => $num++} 
  qw(DONT MICH LEON RAPH SPLN SHRD CASY APRL
     FOOT BEBP RKST DUBY SAMH GRAW KNYN);

foreach (@tableb){
  chomp;
  my ($netsta, $delay_time) = (split /\s+/)[1,9];
  my ($net, $sta) = split /\./,$netstat;

  print "$net $sta\n"
  $stat = $staionNumbers_ZJ{$sta} if ($net eq "ZJ")
  print OUT "$stat \n";
  warn "\$stat: $stat>>$_<<\n"   # for diagnostics
}
```

Comment: It's a very good and valid point - but I'm not sure it actually answers the question, since what we've got is a code dump with insufficient information.